# Команда git branch ничего не выводит

Tags: git, git-branch

Команда `git branch` ничего не пишет, также нет ошибок:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: так может никакого репозитория у тебя и нет внутри этой папки? Ты делал там git init или git clone?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если бы там не было git-репозитория, git написал бы `fatal: not a git repository ...`

Answer (score 3):

Единственная известная мне штатная ситуация, при которой `git branch` ничего не выводит, это абсолютно пустой репозиторий, которой создан командой `git init` и ещё не содержит ни одного коммита.

С точки зрения git'а, ветка (branch) — это указатель на коммит. Если коммитов нет, то и веток быть не может.

Вы можете создать пустой коммит (без файлов), указав параметр `--allow-empty` для команды `git commit`, и далее git будет вести себя более привычно.